# Space causes command not to complete

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have a device that has some built in scripts to allow limited actions. I need to try and issue a second command on the device using the scripts as they are. Every device has the same script, so if I modify the script I will need to do this on every box which is impractical.

The script (create.sh) appears like so:

```
create_directory)
        mkdir "$2"
        ;;
```

Therefore if I do the following in the shell

```
create.sh create_directory test
```

I get a directory called test. What I need to do is make the directory and restart a service, for example:

```
create.sh create_directory test&&service apache2 restart
```

The issue I have is that the space after service breaks the command as it considers each space to be a break between arguments passed to the script. This is the only way in which I can interface with the device and therefore this is the only way I can achieve what i need.

Is there anyway to achieve a second command as mentioned or is there potentially a workaround ie \20 for example is hex for space as I understand and therefore an alternative to a space character may work for me.

Comment: You can use quotes to prevent the word-splitting (`create.sh create_directory "test&&service apache2 restart"`) but that won't help you get the command executed because the `mkdir "$2"` call is (correctly) quoting the argument so it won't get split there either and you will end up creating a `test&&service apache2 restart` directory.

Comment: You can try to see if some other available action is exploitable but realize that is what you are doing. You are **exploiting** the script. So anything you find would be a bug in the script and if it is written well it will not allow you to do this. (As that is generally the point of limited action controls.)

Comment: You could resort to installing a web server presumably PHP, then a simple bash script to communicate with said web server and retrieve a few lines of bash & execute, this would minimize the man-power of having to go to each computer and modifying the script? I did something like this a while ago to support remote booting to a set of VSphere clients.. That aside you have some problems in the CLI Code also, which I can be no assistance of

Comment: You have embedded a shell command in the text of a question and sent it to a web server. Do you think that server should eventually execute your command? If not, why do you expect your device to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Write a script that calls `create.sh` and then restarts apache2.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

create.sh create_directory test
service apache2 restart
```

If you save the script as `myscript.sh` and then

```
chmod 755 myscript.sh
```

you can then call it like

```
./myscript.sh
```

and it will combine your two commands into one and yes, you will need to copy this new command to each of your "devices".

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was the following:

```
./test.sh echo_var test1;what="service restart apache2";$what
```

This means the spaces are never caught by the script